# Prove that a linear transformation can be represented as upper triangle matrix where the basis is orthonormal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, orthonormal, jordan-normal-form

> Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a $\Bbb C$-linear transformation. Prove that $T$ can be represented as an upper triangle matrix $[T]_B$ where $B$ is an orthonormal basis.

The question was asked in the context of Jordan forms and invariant subspaces.
Any idea of how to prove this?

Comment: What is the meaning of $C$ ?

Comment: V is over the complex field.

Comment: This is known as the [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) of a matrix.  Look up a proof, and let us know if you get stuck.